# Inferring properties of the sum of R.V.s from the copula

Tags: joint-distribution, copula, marginal-distribution, actuarial-science

This is not a completely well defined question, so even help making it coherent will be useful.

Setting: Suppose I know the **marginal distributions** of random variables describing the expected losses from two risky events, $L_1$ and $L_2$. I am interested in the sum of the losses, $L=L_1+L_2$. I would like to say something like "when the correlation between $L_1$ and $L_2$ increases, the distribution of the sum $L$ changes in some way (e.g. the  tails get fatter, the middle gets thinner)".

But I want to make statements that depend only on the correlation/covariance structure between $L_1$ and $L_2$, not on the particular shape of either.

Hence I am hopeful that just by looking at the covariance structure of the corresponding copula, I could make statements for any joint distribution with the same copula.

For example, write $C(u_1,u_2)$ for the copula correspinding to $(L_1,L_2)$. I want to prove something like: Suppose if the correlation $Corr(U_1,U_2)$ (or some measure) increases the distribution of $U_1+U_2$ undergoes a mean-preserving spread (or something), then if the $Corr(L_1,L_2)$ increases the distribution of $L_1+L_2$ also undergoes a mean-preserving spread.

In general, I would like to know if / any examples of reasoning on the sum of risks of the copula is sufficient for similar conclusions for the sum of the original risks.

THanks!

Comment: Carrying out such a program would be difficult, because the copula tells you so very little about the sum of the original random variables. The problem is that the distribution of the sum depends so strongly on the marginal distributions. For instance, without knowing the marginals you can't say whether the sum is bounded or even if it has finite expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course whuber is completely right in his comment. So just a qualitative idea to support your further thinking.

Imagine an insurance or investment portfolio of many policies/investments. The total loss of this portfolio can be large if either one or just a few of the risks turn really bad or if many somewhat bad outcomes occur together. For the former you need the margins but with a copula you can address the latter phenomenon.

As guide to your analysis you should choose indicators which only depend on the copula. (Pearson) Correlation is not very useful as it also depends on the margins. In light of the above example I like to define a small probability say p=5% and define a "bad outcome" for a margin $L_i$ as the indicator function $1_{L>l(p)}$ where $l(p)$ is the p-quantile of $L_i$. Now you can analyse the number of bad outcomes, i.e. the sum of the indicators $1_{L_i>l(p)}$ instead of the sum of the $L_i$.

The distribution of this sum only depends on the copula no longer on the margins. If all risks are independent this is a binomial distribution. If you have dependency, the distribution will put more weight on larger number of bad outcomes. In this way you have good control over the above mentioned second reason for large total losses, those from the dependency of your risks.

For further reading Chapter 8 of this [book](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Actuarial+Theory+for+Dependent+Risks%3A+Measures%2C+Orders+and+Models-p-9780470014929) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.